# jQuery, .data('X') returns one value instead an array

Tags: jquery

I have this problem.

```
$(".myClass");
```

returns

```
[
<div class='myClass' data-hotel='1' style='myStyle'></div>
<div class='myClass' data-hotel='2' style='myStyle'></div>
<div class='myClass' data-hotel='3' style='myStyle'></div>
]
```

why then `$(".myClass").data('hotel');` only returns '1'?

i tried `$(".myClass").data();` but returns `Object {hotel: 1}`

Comment: you need to iterate through each element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per docs **[`data(key)`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2)** returns first element value :

> Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or **return the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of matched elements**.

Use **[`map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map)** to iterate over elements and return required data inside callback . Get the result array using **[`get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get)**.

```js
var res = $(".myClass").map(function() {
  return $(this).data('hotel');
}).get();

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='myClass' data-hotel='1' style='myStyle'></div>
<div class='myClass' data-hotel='2' style='myStyle'></div>
<div class='myClass' data-hotel='3' style='myStyle'></div>
```

Comment: @Gil : glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute .each loop for retrieving all values and can push these into an array -

```
var values = [];
$('.myClass').each(function(i, obj) {
   values.push(obj);// can also use attr data-hotel
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [];
var div = $('.myClass')
$.each(div, function() {
  arr.push($(this).data('hotel'))
})

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='myClass' data-hotel='1' style='myStyle'></div>
<div class='myClass' data-hotel='2' style='myStyle'></div>
<div class='myClass' data-hotel='3' style='myStyle'></div>
```

Iterate through each div